# Why is the creature in my evolution simulator acting dumb?

Tags: python, linear-regression, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, evolutionary-algorithm

I tried to make a evolution simulator.  So I started with a creature first. But instead of going towards the food, this guy is sorta going front-back,front-back.
So,what is the problem with this???
I have two modules in my code,one is the main,other is Think-made by me. Both of them are given below. Please see what problem is there.
Main module=>

```
import turtle,random,Think,time

world=turtle.Screen()
world.setup(400,400)#O(0,0),X(180,0),X'(-185,0),Y(0,185),Y'(0,-180)

def growfood():
food=turtle.Turtle()
food.color("green")
food.shape("circle")
food.shapesize(0.4)
food.penup()
food.speed(0)
food.goto(random.randint(-185,180),random.randint(-180,185))
return food

class Creature:
  body=None
  brain=Think.neuron()

 def __init__(self):
   self.body=turtle.Turtle()
   #self.body.penup()
   self.body.color("blue")
   self.body.shape("square")
   self.body.shapesize(0.5)

 def move(self,y,x,dely,delx):
    self.body.goto(self.body.xcor()+x*5,self.body.ycor()+y*5)
    ny=(food.ycor()-self.body.ycor())-dely
    nx=(food.xcor()-self.body.xcor())-dely
        self.brain.adjust(dely, delx, ny/5, nx/5, y, x)

 def locatefood(self):
   delx=food.xcor()-self.body.xcor()
   dely=food.ycor()-self.body.ycor()
   return dely,delx

  def think(self):
        dely,delx=self.locatefood()
        y,x=self.brain.think(dely,delx)
        print("(x,y)=("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
        self.move(y,x,dely,delx)

crt=Creature()      
food=growfood()
run=0
while run<120:
  world.update()
  crt.think()
  if crt.body.distance(food)<15:
    food=growfood()
  time.sleep(1)
```

Think module=>

```
from math import tanh
from random import random


class neuron:
biasy,biasx=1,1
lr=1
weighty,weightx,weightby,weightbx=random(),random(),random(),random()
def adjust(self,dely,delx,ny,nx,y,x):
        #adjust y
        erry=ny-y
        self.weighty+=erry*dely*self.lr
    self.weightby+=erry*self.biasy*self.lr
        #adjust x
    errx=nx-x
    self.weightx+=errx*delx*self.lr
    self.weightbx+=erry*self.biasx*self.lr

def think(self,dely,delx):
    y=dely*self.weighty+self.biasy*self.weightby
        x=delx*self.weightx+self.biasx*self.weightbx
        y=tanh(y)
        print(y)
    if y>0:
       y=1
    elif y<0:
       y=-1
    else:
       y=0
        x=tanh(x)
     print(x)
    if x>0:
        x=1
    elif x<0:
        x=-1
        else:
        x=0
    return y,x
```

Thank you : )

Comment: This is my first question, so I am not so experienced in creating a good question.  So there might be mistakes,and there is some indentions a bit more or less in the code. Sorry for all the inconvenience. Thank you again : )

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please fix the indentation, and your question will be that much better! The code must be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); otherwise, it makes it very difficult for us to help you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) should contain everything you need to know to ask good questions, write good answers, and just be a good member of SO in general.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But if I do not give the full code,how will it be reproducible?  I really appreciate all advices. : )

Comment: Indentation fixed. Thanks @Sylvester Kruin

Comment: Any advice about how I can make this code minimal while keeping it reproducible?

Comment: make a fixed point of food and a crit with just locatefood and move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of code issues, first there appears to be a typo here:

```
self.weightbx+=erry*self.biasx*self.lr
```

based on symmetry, I would have expected `errx`, not `erry`.  The next problem I have with the code is this:

```
ny=(food.ycor()-self.body.ycor())-dely
nx=(food.xcor()-self.body.xcor())-dely
```

Besides the `dely` vs. `delx` symmetry problem, I would have expected you to strip the signs of these numbers and use the signs you calculated:

```
ny = abs(food.ycor() - self.body.ycor()) * dely
nx = abs(food.xcor() - self.body.xcor()) * delx
```

To try to get ahead of these symmetry issues, I've rewritten your code below to do vector math, when possible, rather than calculate individual coordinates.  (This breaks down somewhat as the turtle `Vec2D` multiplication operation is an inner product, and not simply a multiplication of coordinates.)

**Think.py**

```
from math import tanh, copysign
from random import random
from turtle import Vec2D

class neuron:
    lr = 1
    bias = Vec2D(1, 1)
    weight = Vec2D(random(), random())
    weightb = Vec2D(random(), random())

    def adjust(self, delta, guess, position):
        error = (guess - position) * self.lr

        self.weight += Vec2D(error[0] * delta[0], error[1] * delta[1])
        self.weightb += Vec2D(error[0] * self.bias[0], error[1] * self.bias[1])

    def think(self, delta):
        x = delta[0] * self.weight[0] + self.bias[0] * self.weightb[0]
        y = delta[1] * self.weight[1] + self.bias[1] * self.weightb[1]

        return Vec2D(copysign(1, tanh(x)), copysign(1, tanh(y)))
```

**main program:**

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from random import randint
from Think import neuron

class Creature:
    body = Turtle()
    brain = neuron()

    def __init__(self):
        self.body.hideturtle()
        self.body.color('blue')
        self.body.shape('square')
        self.body.shapesize(0.5)
        #self.body.penup()
        self.body.showturtle()

    def move(self, position, delta):
        self.body.goto(self.body.position() + position)
        guess = self.locatefood()
        guess = Vec2D(abs(guess[0]) * delta[0], abs(guess[1]) * delta[1])
        self.brain.adjust(delta, guess, position)

    def locatefood(self):
        return food.position() - self.body.position()

    def think(self):
        delta = self.locatefood()
        position = self.brain.think(delta)
        self.move(position, delta)

def growfood(previous):
    if previous:  # don't waste food!
        food = previous
        food.hideturtle()
        food.color('orange')
        food.stamp()
    else:
        food = Turtle()
        food.hideturtle()
        food.shape('circle')
        food.shapesize(0.4)
        food.penup()

    food.color('green')
    food.goto(randint(-37, 36), randint(-36, 37))
    food.showturtle()

    return food

def seek():
    global run, food

    crt.think()

    if crt.body.distance(food) < 2:
        food = growfood(food)

    if run > 0:
        run -= 1
        world.ontimer(seek, 1000)  # milliseconds

world = Screen()
world.setup(400, 400)
world.setworldcoordinates(-40, -40, 40, 40)  # scaled by 5

run = 120
food = growfood(None)
crt = Creature()

seek()

world.exitonclick()
```

My code might be wrongheaded simulation-wise, but is mainly to enlighten you about alternate techniques when working with the turtle library.  E.g. using `ontimer()` instead of `sleep()`; using `setworldcoordinates()` to build in an implicit scale factor rather than multiplying and dividing each time; resusing turtles as they are a global entity that don't get garbage collected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually my exams are coming so I have to put a pause on coding for a while. That's why I wanted to get this idea running as quickly as possible so that when I come back I can directly move on to further developments. So I did a lots of "copy previous line with y-paste it-replace the y with x"-stuff to complete it fast. But,well..you know..Haste makes waste! And about the vector, copysign..etc -thing, actually this is my first time doing an actual ml stuff and I know absolutely nothing about how vector math works. I am also not knowledgeable about ontimer(). I guess I tried.  : )

Comment: Also,can you please tell me how to destroy a turtle in python. Not it’s drawings,as google is stuck to that. I want to destroy a turtle object.  Is there any way to that?

Comment: I am also kinda curious about what you ment by "to strip the signs of these numbers and use the signs you calculated"